# High page rendering time when creating an html table dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, html-table, settimeout

I am creating a html table dynamically with PHP. But the page rendering gets stuck when the rows and column size increases. It works fine with low values. Here is my code. I know its because of the loop. Can some one suggest a better way?

```
<?php
echo "<table>"; 
for($tr = 1; $tr <= 1000; $tr++){ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    for($td = 1; $td <= 1000; $td++){ 
            echo "<td>x</td>";
        }               
    } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: @Tadeck: Sorry, I didn't understand that. How pagination works when I have to show the entire data on a single table?

Comment: How slow are we talking here? Besides the fact PHP is now looping through 1 million loops, its also outputting a larger amount of text to the browser, same as how a 100kb flat .html file page would take longer then a 3kb .html file. Also I dont see the point of the inner loop when youre just reassigning x to $content 1000x before you use it between td tags, its still just x the whole time

Comment: @user632347: Basically you have stated, that your page stucks, when it is too big (it is too big - it won't generate faster, you may only make it to send you results as it processes them, but see conclusion) and you asked if "_Can some one suggest a better way?_". The solution is to split the results - like Twitter shows all of the tweets, or Facebook renders timeline. Use AJAX magic to pull chunks one-bye-one and this way your page won't be broken (you will have complete HTML at the beginning) and you will achieve what you wanted (display everything). PS. Anyway, why show all at once?

Comment: @WebChemist : x can be any data for that cell

Comment: @Tadeck : creating the table with ajax is a good solution. The particular type of usage of this table makes me to show whole data in the beginning. But I will reconsider the possibility of ajax.

Comment: @Tadeck : why its need to load whole table in beggining ? : User may some time wants to enter the value of the cell in row 1000, column 1000. In that case i have to show the entire table.

Comment: I understand x is a placeholder, I was just pointing out you would only get 1 td the way you had it before the edit but I see you fixed that

Comment: @user632347: You do not need rows 1-999, if user just wants to enter something in row 1000, you just need row 1000. The question is how you will do it - transferring everything will be both slow and impractical, better to load it part by part. And if users will actually use it, pagination is one of the best things you can do to them (preferably seamlessly loading and destroying table parts when they browse the document). It is a design (system design and UI design) problem, not a simple "loop is too slow" problem.